# Allow selecting but not editing a chart and slicers in a protected Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to share an excel file that has slicers and charts in it. I want users to be able to use the slicers for filtering and then select and copy the charts. But I want to protect the sheet and prevent any editing of the chart and the slicers.
As far as I can see, the options are to lock the charts and slicers, in which case they are uneditable when the sheet is protected, but then the slicers are frosen and the chart can't be copied (PrintScreen is not an option). OR, to unlock them, in which case they become usable but editable.
Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you concerned about people permanently messing up your file or are you concerned with them manipulating the file to be able to print / copy a false chart? I.E., would making it read-only be acceptable? What about a solution that uses VBA? Is that an option?

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/538900-how-select-copy-but-not-move-edit-protected-charts.html#post2664377

Comment: @Engineer Toast, read only is nice but not enough - I need to prevent messing with the charts and slicers during the session. VBA is definitely an option.

Comment: @Vojtěch Dohnal -  thanks, that looks like a nice solution for copying the chart, but doesn't solve the slicer problem...

Comment: Why don't you put password protection in your slicer if you are facing problem with your slicer. I can provide you the steps to add password.

Comment: If this will enable the users to select options on the slicer but not to be able to delete or edit it otherwise then I definitely would like to use this option - I'd be grateful if you can provide the steps.

Comment: Here is the link plz go through this and do inform if this was helpful for you or not. http://www.auditexcel.co.za/blog/excel-slicer-with-password-protection/

Comment: I see the suggestion here is the same suggestion that @Vojtěch Dohnal made - to protect the sheet but leave the slicer unlocked. That makes the slicer usable but open to editing and deleting...

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options. One way is to go for VBA enabled worksheet and add your own logic using VBA, but it requires that your sheet is `xlsm` and the end user must enable macros in your workbook - but this way you get best control over allowed user's actions. The second way is with `xlsx` without VBA - but you cannot deny some actions to the user there, like to delete the slicers or change the name of the chart.

1) You can do [as recommended here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/538900-how-select-copy-but-not-move-edit-protected-charts.html#post2664377):

```
Private Sub Chart1_Click()     
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).CopyPicture
    MsgBox ("Chart copied to clipboard.  You can now paste this into another application.")        
End Sub
```

It means you need to convert your workbook to xlsm, workbook with macros. Then add a macro to handle the clipboard action on the chart click.

2) The better way I think would be that you  leave the Chart element unlocked on the protected worksheet and [modify its properties with a macro](http://www.bettersolutions.com/excel/exx823/VU126266332.htm):

```
Sub macro()
ActiveChart.ProtectData = True
ActiveChart.ProtectFormatting = True
ActiveChart.ProtectSelection = False
End Sub
```

or for all charts on a sheet:

```
For Each i In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    i.Chart.ProtectSelection = False
    i.Chart.ProtectData = True
    i.Chart.ProtectFormatting = True 
Next i
```

This way you use macros when creating the workbook, but the workbook itself does not contain VBA.

If you create a separate sheet for a chart, you can protect it separately with a password:

```
Sub macro()
Dim newChart As Chart

Range("C9:C11").Select
Set newChart = ActiveChart

With newChart
.Protect Password:="pwd", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True
.ProtectData = True
.ProtectFormatting = True
.ProtectSelection = False
.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ProtectSelection = False

   'setting other properties
End With

End Sub
```

As for the slicers, you need to leave them unlocked and to check "Use Pivottable Reports" when locking the worksheet.

Comment: Those are some good solutions for the charts problem, thanks. But the problem with the slicer remains: An unlocked slicer in a protected sheet can be deleted and otherwise messed with - I need it to be usable but not editable...

Answer (score 0):

By editing do you mean only the underlying data or styles of the graphs themselves?

If you only want the data to be locked, you could have your data on the protected sheet (where you can also allow using pivots, selecting, sorting etc), and have your graphs on another sheet.

[Here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/538900-how-select-copy-but-not-move-edit-protected-charts.html#post2664377) they suggest to use a macro that copies a graph on click, which is something you could use if the sheet with the graph is also protected.

Comment: My data is protected - it is possible to enable select and copy on the data but not edit. The problem with the chart and slicers is that select and edit are not separable. The "copy chart" button is a nice solution for copying the chart, but I will need a different solution for the slicer...

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling read-only mode. I believe it's a feature on Excel (seperate from Protected View) but I could be wrong.

Comment: Read only is nice but not enough - I need to prevent messing with the charts and slicers during the session.

Comment: I believe Read-Only should prevent that, if I'm familiar enough with it. Either way, the above answer regarding VBA is your best bet, probably.

Comment: I found a pretty nice article on it: http://kb.jetreports.com/article/AA-00907/0/How-to-Restrict-Users-from-Changing-or-Modifying-a-Pivot-Table.html

Comment: This is close to the general Idea, but regretfully still irrelevant to the slicer problem...